# Is it possible to detect the current operating system in Haxe?

Tags: haxe

In Haxe, is there any way to get the name of the current operating system? I'm looking for a way to do this that works in all Haxe target languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Sys.systemName() to obtain the name of the operating system - this works for multiple target languages.

Comment: Does anyone know what value Sys.systemName() returns when targeting mobile platforms via NME/HxCPP?

Comment: @JasonO'Neil I haven't developed any applications for this platform yet - I suppose you could test it yourself using `trace(Sys.systemName)`.